# How to remove git tracking but keep file in repo

Tags: ubuntu, git, version-control, gitlab

1. I **do not** want to delete the file in the repo.
2. I **do want** the file cloned a developers and my machine.
3. However, I do want to ignore the file from future check in/push.

My goal is that only files that are actually modified .c/.h are what shows up after running a git status. I have already modified the .gitignore but the project was uploaded into GitLab including Makefiles and other miscellaneous files that are necessary for building the project but get modified each time anyone does a build on their machine. It just needless garbage on the screen to sift through.

Comment: Generally speaking you use a .gitignore to prevent these files from being added to the repo. I don't believe there is an answer to your question, except perhaps to write a script wrapper for `git status` that shows what you want to see.

Comment: `miscellaneous files that are necessary for building the project` .. what files?  If they are getting modified.. then they are probably junk and should be in your .gitignore.. otherwise.. I can't even guess what you are talking about.

Comment: The project got uploaded with object files, .c/.h files that get "generated" and will get changed each time, .log files that I don't care to track. All these files are tracked, but I don't want them to be tracked. I have added all the files I want to ignore to the gitignore file but I need the files to not be tracked in the future on any other developer's machine and I would rather not create a new project with the updated project with updated gitignore.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas miscellaneous files like Makefile that are currently track, get updated after a built, and files that I don't want tracked and can't delete because it's required for the project to build..

Comment: Your Makefile shouldn't be getting touched by anything unless it is autogenerated (like with CMake).  If autogenerated, it is junk that should be in the .gitignore for that part of the file tree.  What on earth would be modifying the makefile? .. oh.. and I am just trying to help (not criticize).

Comment: For example, there is a Makefile.mk in our project. Currently it has a variable PRJ_FULL_PATH inside. Depending on whatever machine the project gets run on, that path will get updated. Also, inside the Makefile.mk there is a comment: # DO NOT EDIT - file is regenerated whenever the project changes

All that being said, I think my solution is to git rm --cached  the files I want to remove, add them to my .gitignore file if not already there, commit the changes, then push them to the repo.